# flutter location permission from integration test not working

Tags: android, flutter, integration-testing, android-permissions

I am trying to write `integration_test` for my location app. I need to allow location permission from my integration_test.

I have set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in my windows environment variable. I have tested from command prompt & Android Studio terminal and it shows fine from both. https://i.ibb.co/4gDPs3Z/echo-android-sdk-root.jpg

Unfortunately, I am getting  `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` value `null` from `Platform.environment`. I have attached screen shot https://i.ibb.co/t2Y3fBc/android-sdk-root-not-found.jpg

If I hard coded `envVars` to my windows machine's android location `C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe`, then it throws error

`No such file or directory Command: C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe shell pm grant com.dealerapp.mlink android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

below is my source code

```
Future<void> grantLocationPermission() async{

    final Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
    print('evnVars = $envVars');
    print('ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = ${envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT']}');
    final String adbPath = envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT']! + '/platform-tools/adb.exe';
    
    await Process.run(adbPath, [
      'shell',
      'pm',
      'grant',
      'com.abcd.efgh', //my app package
      'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
    ]);
    await Process.run(adbPath, [
      'shell',
      'pm',
      'grant',
      'com.abcd.efgh', //my app package
      'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
    ]);
    await integrationDriver();
}
```

Any suggesion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not work because envVars will give you environment variables of the system where its getting executed. And since you are executing in emulator then platform is Android [`print(Platform.isAndroid)` and see]
Also if you debug you will see the environment variable is not set.

As you might have already figured, integration tests cannot interact with native popups. So following are the only ways I found to fix this

1. **Have a test driver:** I could only solve the problem using steps below

- Create a folder "test_driver"
- Add a file "integration_test_driver.dart"
- Add following content into the file

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Process.run(
   'adb',
   [
     'shell',
     'pm',
     'grant',
     'com.example.<your app name>', // TODO: Update this
     'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
   ],
 );
 // TODO: Add more permissions as required
 await integrationDriver();
}
```

- Create a folder "integration_test"
- Add a file "app_test.dart" and add your test here
- Run test using command 
  `flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test_driver.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart`
- You need to do this only once, after that running the tests directly from Test Explorer will not show pop
- To show the dialog again revoke the permissions using below command in terminal
  `adb shell pm revoke com.example.aries_fe android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

2. **Crude way (not suggested)**

   1. Find the x,y coordinate where you can see the option you want to click on popup
   2. call `tester.tapAt(const Offset(x,y))` in your test

Notes:

- Script with below lines does not work. I wonder why this does not work. Will investigate this further.

```
adb shell pm grant com.example.<your app name> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
flutter test integration_test/login_test.dart
```

- `setUpApp()` does not work either.

Comment: tapAt doesn't work, as it can't interact with native element either. the tap event is only inside Flutter context

Comment: is not work i am using itegration_test 
can help me